# How to create a subfolder in a subsubfolder SharePoint Online C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to create some folders in the document library in C#.

The folder structure should be as follows in the document library:

"98_Projekte" --> "Muster Mandant" --> "01 Test Subfolder"

In my C# code, I only create the sub folder "Muster Mandant" in "98_Projekte". That is correct, but I want afterwards to create new subfolders in "Muster Mandant" (see second foreach).

```
        public static void AddFolder(ClientContext context, string[] folders)
    {
        Web web = context.Web;
        var docLibrary = web.DefaultDocumentLibrary().RootFolder;
        context.Load(docLibrary);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder subFolder in docLibrary.Folders)
        {
            if (subFolder.Name == "98_Projekte")
            {
                subFolder.Folders.Add("Muster Mandant");
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                docLibrary = subFolder;
                docLibrary.Update();
            }
        }
        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder subSubFolder in docLibrary.Folders)
        {
            if (subSubFolder.Name == "Muster Mandant")
            {
                foreach (string folder in folders)
                {
                    subSubFolder.Folders.Add(folder);
                }
            }
        }
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check below code.

```
 public static Folder AddSubFolder(ClientContext context, Folder ParentFolder, string folderName)
        {
            Folder resultFolder=ParentFolder.Folders.Add(folderName);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            return resultFolder;   
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new ClientContext("https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/TST/"))
            {
                string password = "pw";
                SecureString sec_pass = new SecureString();
                Array.ForEach(password.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);
                sec_pass.MakeReadOnly();
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("lee@domain.onmicrosoft.com", sec_pass);               

                Web web = context.Web;
                var folders = web.DefaultDocumentLibrary().RootFolder.Folders;
                context.Load(folders);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (Folder subFolder in folders)
                {
                    if (subFolder.Name == "98_Projekte")
                    {
                       Folder parent1= AddSubFolder(context,subFolder,"Muster Mandant");
                       AddSubFolder(context, parent1, "01 Test Subfolder");   
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Done");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Okay, I understand. I have to use two functions to get the right order instead of two separated foreach loops. Your code works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your code is expecting the .Folders property to contain all folders (recursive) and instead you are just getting the direct children of the root folder.   In your 2nd loop check the context of the docLibrary.Folders property/collection and see what is returned.